# Name A Telemetry Event in App Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I am trying to use App Insights to track button clicks:

```
try
{
   TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
   var ev = new EventTelemetry("buttonCancel_Click");
   telemetry.TrackEvent(ev);
   telemetry.Flush();
}   
catch { }
```

Now, in the azure dashboard the event shows up as buttonCancel_Click (which is the name of the event handler of the buttonCancel's click event). I want to use a better name like "User Cancels Subscription".

I have put the above code in the event handler called buttonCancel_Click in my asp.net web forms application.

I couldn't find any way to do that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.datacontracts.eventtelemetry?view=azure-dotnet

The string passes in the EventTelementry constructor is the name of the  custom event, so :

```
try
{
   TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
   var ev = new EventTelemetry("User Cancels Subscription");
   telemetry.TrackEvent(ev);
   telemetry.Flush();
}   
catch { }
```